# Scapy sniffer: associate sent packet with received answer

Tags: python, scapy, packet-sniffers

I am pretty new to packet sniffing, so my apologies if the question is very easy to answer. I have been playing with Scapy lately for sniffing some packets sent between two servers. However, I would like to check what the second server answered to the request.

I was able to capture both packets in my logs, but I still don't get how to match them to what answers goes with which request. I have tried googling it, but did not get anything on this matter.

Note that Scapy is NOT sending the packet, it is just sniffing everything. Is it possible to associate the correct request/answer?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Are you sniffing TCP or UDP?

Comment: @synthesizerpatel TCP

Comment: Each TCP connection has a session ID associated to it, use that session ID to determine what the response is since generally the communication on a socket will be one session for query && response. (Think HTTP server.. HTTP server sends back a response on the same socket pair that the request came in on..)